# compute Visible property for a button, based upon length of a textarea field

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I would like to calculate the visibility of a button based upon the content of a text area field (multi line edit box). it should contain at least some text.

I could use the onkeypress event (server) and perform a partial refresh on the button BUT I notice that the partial refresh spinner appears then when users are writing in the field. I would like to avoid this.

What options do I have?

Comment: Rob's right, don't ever think about SSJS event. For performance reasons use CSJS with Dojo/jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be best off writing a client side script for that event.  This script should show the button when there are more than 200 characters in the textarea.  You will need to set the style visibility to hidden for the button initially.  If the form can be edited multiple times, you will need to write this as a function and call it on page load as well as in the keypress event.

If you can use the keyup event instead of keypress, this may be better.

```
var textareaID = '#{id:textareaID}';
var buttonID = '#{id:buttonID}';
var textareaValue = document.getElementById(textareaID).value;
var visibility;

if (textareaValue.length > 200) {
    visibility = 'visible';
}
else 
{
    visibility = 'hidden';
}
document.getElementById(buttonID).style.visibility=visibility;
```

Comment: Hello Rob, your code does the trick. It seems I have to go csjs all the way to avoid the partial refresh dialog. instead of setting the visibility style property I have decided to use jquery and set the display property via show() and hide() because the space for a button would be reserved in the UI so an empty space is visible. Thank you for helping me out!